# Evento onDoubleClick en React.js no es captado en dispositivos

Tags: reactjs

Estoy realizando una página sencilla en React.js (la cual estoy adaptando para móvil) y he encontrado que en los eventos de doble click la función handleDoubleClick no responde. Quiero que el usuario al pulsar dos veces sobre una imagen (con el dedo) pueda interactuar con ésta (por ejemplo eliminarla). Éste es un ejemplo muy resumido y directamente al grano:

En React:

```
class onDoubleClick extends React.Component {
      handleDoubleClick = (event) => {
            console.log(event.target.src);
      }
      render(){
            return <img src="UNA URL" className="my-photo" onDoubleClick={this.handleDoubleClick}/>
      }
```

En CSS:

```
.my-photo{
     cursor: pointer;
}
```

He notado que dándole cursor:pointer responde ante eventos de un sólo click, pero sigo sin encontrar solución para los eventos de doble click. Recalco que estoy haciendo las pruebas con Chrome, en el device toolbar. No la probé en un dispositivo real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los navegadores mobile no implementan el evento `dblclick`. En su lugar, debes de crear tu propia implementación.

**Ejemplo**

```
export const onDoubleTap = function(el, handler) {
  const MAX_TIME_TO_SECOND_TAP = 300 // espera máximo 300ms al siguiente click/tap
  let lastTapTimestamp = 0;
  el.addEventListener('touchstart', function() {
    lastTapTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
  });
  el.addEventListener('touchend', function(event) {
      var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
      var tapEllapsedTime = currentTime - lastTapTimestamp;

      // si se ha hecho el segundo tap/click entre los 300ms
      if (tapEllapsedTime < MAX_TIME_TO_SECOND_TAP && tapEllapsedTime > 0) {
          event.preventDefault();
          lastTapTimestamp = 0; // reinicia el counter
          handler(event); // ejecuta el handler
      }
  });
};
```

Para usarlo te bastaría algo como lo siguiente:

```
const imageRef = useRef();

useEffect(function () {
  // Úsalo de esta forma
  onDoubleTap(imageRef.current, function(event) {
    // hacer algo
  });
});

return (
  <img
    src="UNA URL"
    className="my-photo"
    ref={imageRef}
  />
)
```